# How i can upload image with vs-upload to data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuesax

i have problem in my project , in vs-upload i cannot append after img selected to data
for example

```
<vs-upload :data="file" ref="file" limit="1" :show-upload-button="false" action="http://example.local/api/admin/sliders/1/upload" fileName="image" />
```

i have a form to create slider , and have one save button to create slider in backend and i cannot upload slider before create in database

do have you any offer for me?